# geoChoroplethChart is black with two option of value for one key

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, reductio

I have the next data works with dc.js and geoChoroplethChart,

```
var data = crossfilter([
{ state: 'one', bar: 'A', num: '1' },
{ state: 'two', bar: 'B', num: '2' },
{ state: 'three', bar: 'A', num: '3' },
{ state: 'one', bar: 'B', num: '3' },
{ state: 'one', bar: 'A', num: '2' },
{ state: 'two', bar: 'B', num: '2' },
]);


var statedim=data.dimension(function(d){return d['state'];})
var my_group=statedim.group();

reducer=reductio();
reducer.value('nbar').exception(function(d){return d['bar']}.exceptionCount(true);
reducer.value('nnum').exception(function(d){return d['num']}.exceptionCount(true);


reducer(my_group);
```

where state is a region in my country and the color is based on nnum, so I use

```
.valueAccessor(function (d) {return d.value.nnum.exceptionCount})
```

but I want it in the title appear state, nnum and nbar.

```
.title(function(d){
return["state: " +d.key,
"#nnum: "+d.value].join('\n')})
```

but I do not know how to integrate nbar in title without  geoChoroplethChart is black.

I think in use

```
.valueAccessor(function (d) {return d.value})

.title(function(d){
return["state: " +d.key,
"#nnum: "+d.value.nnum.exceptionCount,
"nbar:" +d.value.nbar.exceptionCount].join('\n')})
```

It is the solution for the title, but the states fill up black and when I click on another graphic, the map does not react.

Comment: I don't think I understand - afaik the `valueAccessor` and `title` should be independent, so why not use the option that works for each one?

Comment: If I use valueAccessor this value is fixed to use then in title recognizes only one, which is fixed

Comment: @Gordon I attach the example of the first case, https://jsfiddle.net/ajey2987/f2kggraq/6/ ,
It can be appreciated with console.log that does not allow me to access the other values

Comment: got it, thanks! answering now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the geoChoropleth deals with data is definitely pretty weird. All the other charts bind the crossfilter data to the SVG; [geoChoropleth binds the map data and hides the crossfilter data in an internal object](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1268). Then it fakes bound data for the accessors.

What's more, as you point out, it stores the result of the `valueAccessor()` in its hidden data, rather than binding the raw data and then using the `valueAccessor` when needed. I'm pretty sure that's a bad idea.

But enough complaining. Let's find the workaround, as usual.

Turns out you don't need to drill down in the value accessor in order to get the colors right. You can leave the `valueAccessor` defaulted, and it will fetch `d.value`. Then use the `colorAccessor` to get the colors right:

```
.colorAccessor(function(d){
  return d ? d.nbar.exceptionCount : null;
})
```

Note the guard against undefined data, a result of the same weirdness.

We also need to guard against an undefined `value` in the title accessor, because the chart is building key/value pairs from the map data, not the crossfilter data:

```
.title(function(d){
  var arr = ["state: " + d.key];
  if(d.value) // have to guard against null data for "other" states
    arr.push(
     "#nnum: "+d.value.nnum.exceptionCount,
     "nbar:" +d.value.nbar.exceptionCount
    );
  return arr.join('\n');
})
```

Fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/7qb3yujj/14/

Comment: Thank you so much! You're amazing.